# Entity Framework not loading one-to-one child object stored in the same table

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-one

Here are the definitions of my EF objects. It contains an Article containing article metadata and a ArticleClob containing the actual text. Both are mapped to the same table ForumArticle. The idea was to be able to fetch text only when necessary.

```
  [Table("ForumArticle")]
  public class CxForumArticle
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(512)] 
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    ...
    [MaxLength(1024)]
    public string Teaser { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("ArticleId")]
    public virtual CxForumArticleClob TextInfo { get; set; }
    ...
  }

  [Table("ForumArticle")]
  public class CxForumArticleClob
  {
    [Key]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ArticleId")]
    public virtual CxForumArticle Article { get; set;}
    [MaxLength(409600)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
  }
```

Here is the mapping definition in my DB Context file

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CxForumArticle>().HasRequired(c => c.TextInfo).WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

When I try to fetch it using "Include", it returns null for TextInfo. What can be wrong?

Here is how I query the object

```
 using (var ctx = new CxForumContext())
      {
        ctx.Database.Log = MyDebug.Write;

        CxForumArticle retVal = ctx.Articles
          .Include("TextInfo")
          .Where(a => a.ArticleId == articleId).First();

        //var txt = retVal.TextInfo;

        ctx.Entry(retVal).State = EntityState.Detached;

        return retVal;
      }
    }
```

Here is the intercepted SQL

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[ArticleId] AS [ArticleId], 
    [Limit1].[Alias] AS [Alias], 
    [Limit1].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Limit1].[Teaser] AS [Teaser], 
    [Limit1].[AudioId] AS [AudioId], 
    [Limit1].[ArticleType] AS [ArticleType], 
    [Limit1].[UnifiedContentId] AS [UnifiedContentId], 
    [Limit1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
    [Limit1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
    [Limit1].[ModifiedOn] AS [ModifiedOn], 
    [Limit1].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], 
    [Limit1].[PublishingStatus] AS [PublishingStatus], 
    [Limit1].[EditorComments] AS [EditorComments], 
    [Limit1].[Text] AS [Text]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[ArticleId] AS [ArticleId], 
        [Extent1].[Alias] AS [Alias], 
        [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
        [Extent1].[Teaser] AS [Teaser], 
        [Extent1].[AudioId] AS [AudioId], 
        [Extent1].[ArticleType] AS [ArticleType], 
        [Extent1].[UnifiedContentId] AS [UnifiedContentId], 
        [Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
        [Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
        [Extent1].[ModifiedOn] AS [ModifiedOn], 
        [Extent1].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], 
        [Extent1].[PublishingStatus] AS [PublishingStatus], 
        [Extent1].[EditorComments] AS [EditorComments], 
        [Extent1].[Text] AS [Text]
        FROM [dbo].[ForumArticle] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ArticleId] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

This happens both with lazy loading on and off.

Comment: I split the table. Now I have a separate table for a clob, which has its own primary key, and the main table referencing the clob table using a foreign key. And I removed one-to-one declaration from context. So now I have a one-clob-to-many-articles relationship. But I still get null instead of TextInfo in my query

Answer (score 0):

Use Strongly types version of query.

```
CxForumArticle retVal = ctx.Articles
          .Include(t=>t.TextInfo)
          .Where(a => a.ArticleId == articleId).First();
```

Comment: The same result. And the same SQL under the hood

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in

```
ctx.Entry(retVal).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Once I removed this line, I saw that everything works as expected.

This code sets all related objects to NULL. I thought it would be an easy way to serialize an object and a few of its dependents, that are already populated by using Include(), but unfortunately JSON serialization of EF objects is not that straightforward.